# SSIS Derived Column Expression for CASE.. WHEN

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssis

I have the following SQL code that I am trying to convert inao a SSIS 2012 Derived Column Expression:

```
QUATER= 
        CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(M, @BD) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Q1'
            WHEN DATEPART(M, @BD) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'Q2'
            ELSE 'OTHER'
        END
```

My Expression looks like this, and it works:

```
DATEPART("M", @[User::BD]) == 1 ? "Q1":
(DATEPART("M", @[User::BD]) == 2 ? "Q1":
(DATEPART("M", @[User::BD]) == 3 ? "Q1":
(DATEPART("M", @[User::BD]) == 4 ? "Q2":
(DATEPART("M", @[User::BD]) == 5 ? "Q2":
(DATEPART("M", @[User::BD]) == 6 ? "Q2" : "OTHER"
)))))
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much more exciting, but this should be equivalent:

```
DATEPART("M", @[User::BD]) <= 3 ? "Q1":
(DATEPART("M", @[User::BD]) <= 6 ? "Q2" : "OTHER"
)
```

Likewise You could use quarter instead of month:

```
DATEPART("q", @[User::BD]) <= 2 ? "Q"+DATEPART("q", @[User::BD]) : "OTHER"
```

Can't test that string concatenation, you may need to convert the `DATEPART()` output to text.

Comment: Thank you, this looks much better!